# Need help looping a notebook evaluation

Tags: programming, evaluation

I'm a new user and would like to find the minimum value of soln1[30] obtained after repeating the following evaluation (below) for 1000 cycles (for instance).  I can obtain sequential values of soln[30] if I reevaluate the entire notebook manually each time, but I want to be able to automate this process until a minimum value of soln1[30] is reached.  The difficulty that I am encountering is that the entire notebook requires evaluation in order to generate a different random integer each time- I am having trouble figuring out how to force the evaluation to include the randominteger step using commands like Table, etc.  I'm probably missing something simple- any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance...

```
Clear[w, t, q, soln1]

f1[t_] := 5*t;

w = RandomInteger[{1111, 9999}];
a = IntegerDigits[w][[1]];
b = IntegerDigits[w][[2]];
c = IntegerDigits[w][[3]];
d = IntegerDigits[w][[4]];
p = 0.1;
k = 0.6;

end1 = a;
p1 = end1 + p;
end2 = p1 + b;
p2 = end2 + p;
end3 = p2 + c;
p3 = end3 + p;
end4 = p3 + d;

soln1[t_] := Piecewise[{{f1[t], t < end1}, {k*f1[end1], 
 end1 <= t < p1}, {f1'[t]*(t - p1) + k*f1[end1], 
 p1 <= t < epnd2}, {k*f1[end2], 
 end2 <= t < p2}, {f1'[t]*(t - p2) + k*f1[end2], 
 p2 <= t < end3}, {k*f1[end3], 
 end3 <= t < p3}, {f1'[t]*(t - p3) + k*f1[end3], p3 <= t <= 30}}];

 soln1[30]
```

Comment: Welcome to SE.  It would help if you would explain in simple terms what `soln1` is intended to do.  What do you want to vary and what do you want to keep invariant as you iterate?  You can and should eliminate several variables.  `a, b, c`, and `d` are all produced by RandomInteger[9]. No need for them to be defined outside `soln1`, if at all.

Comment: Have a look at `Module`, `Do` and `CompoundExpression` (`;`).

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to your code, and iterates dynamically:

```
f1[t_] := 5*t
p = 1/10;   k = 6/10; r = {};
SeedRandom[42];
Dynamic[ Refresh[
   a = (IntegerDigits@RandomInteger[{1111, 9999}])[[;; 3]];
   AppendTo[r, N[f1'[30]*(30 - Tr@a - 3 p) + k*f1[Tr@a + 2 p]]];
   {ListLinePlot@r, Min@r}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Perhaps better:

```
r = {FromDigits@#, N[f1'[30]*(30 - Tr@# - 3 p) + k*f1[Tr@# + 2 p]]} & /@ 
                                                             IntegerDigits@Range[110, 999];
{ListLinePlot@r, Pick[r, Thread[#[[2]] == Min[r[[All, 2]]]] & /@ r]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: belisarius, rereading [your comments](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/830/hat-dash-2012-poll#comment2836_830) regarding "Hat Dash" I had a good chuckle seeing as you are sporting a "hat" this year. XD

Comment: Thanks to all for the comments.  Belisarius, your code is exactly what I needed- I learned a lot by examining it.  Is there any way that I could get a read out of the actual random integer value that is associated with the min@r value?  Thanks again.  Steve

Comment: @user11287 Just change `{ListLinePlot@r, Min@r}` by `{ListLinePlot[r[[All, 2]]], {FromDigits@#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ 
  Select[r, #[[2]] == Min[r[[All, 2]]] &]}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm NOT supporting it. The overall effects on the site don't look good. I'm just trying it to understand it better.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12783059#12783059

Comment: @belisarius- Brilliant, and thanks again!  I would not have been able to figure this out myself at this stage.  I appreciate the help.  Steve